# How i can use stringWithContentOfFile while text is not UTF8 format

Tags: iphone, xcode, ipad

I have many files html type. Now i want to get content of them. But the text is not UTF8 format so stringWithContentOfFile function return nil. The problem is i can't convert text of file to UTF8 because there are many files. I tried use WebView but not success. There are any way to read files?

Answer (score 0):

Get the data using `dataWithContentsOfFile:` method and then convert it into an `NSString` object using `initWithData:encoding:` method. You can provide the encoding there.

```
NSData * data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:filePath];
NSString * fileInString = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:data encoding:yourEncoding];
```

Comment: The result is nil with NSUTF8StringEncoding:(.

Comment: But you said it is not `NSUTF8StringEncoding`. How will it work if you use it?

Comment: Usually when i want to use i must convert text to UTF8 format. But there are a lot of files. So i can't convert by hands.

Comment: All of encoding return exactly the content.